# We aren't voting enough!

Tags: discussion, voting

In 2014, Mark Mayo recommended to [Vote early and vote often](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/q/194/6).

In the past quarter, [only 8 users voted more than 10 times](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=quarter), including 0 moderators  (assuming the user voting report can be trusted).

[image: past quarter]

In the past year, [62 users voted more than ten times](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users?page=1&tab=voters&filter=year), including 1 moderator.

Either our content is very bad, or we simply aren't voting enough.

I don't believe our content is very bad.

Comment: Something looks odd here, as I definitely did upvotes in both October and September this year (and generally do vote on posts every month), but they don't appear in this list

Comment: Is there a bug in the measurements?

Comment: The tooltip for "Voters" filter says: "Users who voted more than 10 times"

Comment: @AndrewT. Good find. I have edited the body of the "question".

Comment: Hmm. I also feel this is dodgy. I've been away for all of Sep and Oct really, aside from some flags, but the rest of the year - my quest  to reduce unanswered questions meant I was often looking to vote up new answers....

Comment: Even "very bad" content should attract votes.  Perhaps the content is very indifferent.

Comment: @phoog Sounds like [radical centrism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_centrism).

Comment: Ha! I didn't realize this was a problem. Looking at my voting history, I definitely don't vote enough. Most of the times I don't have enough information about a country to decide if the post is a good post and the other times, the post is utter garbage. Nonetheless I should definitely be voting more.

Comment: @DipenShah If the post is utter garbage, you should downvote.  And you can upvote questions even if you don't have a clue about the answer.

Comment: @gerrit I completely agree. Like I said I wasn't aware this was an issue.